# Pfsense openvpn cannot reach a remote private IP via tunnel

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, openvpn, pfsense

I am trying to reach to a private ip address on a specific port from my production network.

1) I connect from my home to production network via openvpn(configured on pfsense), gets IP 192.168.4.31

2) Inside this pfsense server, there is a tunnel created using ipsec from my prod network to a remote network end point.

3) I am trying to reach a private ip under that remote network through above vpn connection described in point 1.

If this question is incomplete or more details are needed, kindly ask i will elaborate further.

Please advise.

Comment: You're likely missing routes between the two endpoints. I don't think PFsense would share that the ip's on the of the ipsec tunnel, with those on the openvpn side, unless you specifically configure it to.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what it is you're doing... you don't specify `tun` or `tap`, or explain how you have DNS configured for your OpenVPN server. But, just a couple of thoughts for whatever they're worth: 1) tlook at OPNsense instead of pfsense (many reasons), and 2) consider posting to the [OpenVPN forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/) if you haven't already. Your question is fairly specific, and that's where one goes for OpenVPN answers  :)

Comment: Can you post the firewall rules for these interfaces please. If they are both directly connected to pfsense, both links should be in the routing table. I would be interested to see that also. Regards

Comment: @djsmiley2k I just found there is no interface added to the openvpn server configured on pfsense. I added one and then tried to connect vpn, no access to LAN but all public internet works via vpn. I reverted the changes for now.